# templateUrl Not Working with in AngularJs Directives

Tags: angularjs

This is my Index page

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/efDirective.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/EmployeeForms.js"></script>

<html ng-app="AngularModule">
<body>
    <div employee-form></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is DirectiveJs

```
var app = angular.module("AngularModule", []);
    app.directive("employeeForm", function () {
        debugger;
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            //template: 'helloworld',
            templateUrl: 'Content/efTemplate.html'
        }
    });
```

Content in efTemplate.html is not displaying on index.cshtml page.

Answer (score 0):

Check the message in browser console, probably there will be some error message. Maybe the url to template is not correctly resolved?
Did you specify the base url for angular?

The other option is to pre-render the template directly in your html index file. That has the benefit of saving the extra http request.
Like this:

```
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="templateUrl">
  <h1>your template </h1>
 </script>
```

Example here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script